# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined for deployed version only in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, axios, typeerror

My application's intent is to retrieve user data/comments from firestore and display the information the information on the users profile page. This works flawlessly locally, but once I deployed it, I receive the TypeError. Why would this work locally, but not in the deployed version and what would be the fix?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import Comment from '../components/comment/Comment';
import StaticProfile from '../components/profile/StaticProfile';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

import CommentSkeleton from '../util/CommentSkeleton';
import ProfileSkeleton from '../util/ProfileSkeleton';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { getUserData } from '../redux/actions/dataActions';

class user extends Component {
  state = {
    profile: [],
    commentIdParam: []
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const handle = this.props.match.params.handle;
    const commentId = this.props.match.params.commentId;

    if (commentId) this.setState({ commentIdParam: commentId });

    this.props.getUserData(handle);
    axios
      .get(`/user/${handle}`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          profile: res.data.user
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }
  render() {
    const { comments, loading } = this.props.data;
    const { commentIdParam } = this.state;

    const commentsMarkup = loading ? (
      <CommentSkeleton />
    ) : comments === null ? (
      <p>No comments from this user</p>
    ) : !commentIdParam ? (
      comments.map((comment) => <Comment key={comment.commentId} comment={comment} />)
    ) : (
      comments.map(comment => {
        if(comment.commentId !== commentIdParam)
          return <Comment key={comment.commentId} comment={comment} />;
        else return <Comment key={comment.commentId} comment={comment} openDialog />;
      })
    );

    return (
      <Grid container spacing={16}>
        <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
          {this.state.profile === null ? (
            <ProfileSkeleton />
          ) : (
            <StaticProfile profile={this.state.profile} />
          )}
        </Grid>
        <Grid item sm={4} xs={12}>
          {commentsMarkup}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

user.propTypes = {
  getUserData: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  data: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  data: state.data
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getUserData }
)(user);
```

Comment: are you possibly getting a cors error in production? are you only getting the error that states cannot read property of map of undefined?

Comment: The "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined -  at a.value (user.js:44)" is the only error I am receiving.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can determine what your problem is exactly without more information how you populate `this.props.data` and what that data looks like but if I had to guess, I'd say it looks like `this.props.data.comments` doesn't exist.

If `this.props.data` doesn't have comments property your `comments` variable would be undefined not null like you're checking. You could check for undefined and render the same thing as you do for null and that probably would fix it but you may want to default the comments property on data to an empty array.

Comment: it works for him in dev just not production so I can only assume it has something to do with data not being available in production

Comment: @RobertTerrell I'm not disagreeing with that. In fact, my explanation is most likely why he's encountering that particular error. Like I said in my answer, it's hard to determine the root cause with this limited amount of information but it does seem to be with how `this.props.data` is populated. It could be something with their build not having a particular env var. There are a lot of possibilities.